# Get Integer.class as result in NamedNativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I have an entity (StockKeepingUnit) with NamedNativeQuery:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = StockKeepingUnit.NQ_FINDBY_ARTICLE_AND_SIZE, resultClass = StockKeepingUnit.class, hints = {
        @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.fetchSize", value = "1"),
        @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.readOnly", value = "true") }, query = "SELECT * "
            + "FROM StockKeepingUnit sku " + "WHERE sku.article = :articleNumber "
            + "AND sku.size = :size " + "AND sku.deleted = 0")
```

Call in Java:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery(StockKeepingUnit.NQ_FINDBY_ARTICLE_AND_SIZE);
query.setParameter(StockKeepingUnit.NQ_PARAM_ARTICLE_NR, articleNumber);
query.setParameter(StockKeepingUnit.NQ_PARAM_SIZE, size);

return (StockKeepingUnit) query.getSingleResult();
```

With this query I want only select the sku.stockKeepingUnitNumber and get an Integer-Value as result when I execute this query.

I tried something like this, but this did not work...

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = StockKeepingUnit.NQ_FINDBY_ARTICLE_AND_SIZE, resultClass = Integer.class, hints = {
        @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.fetchSize", value = "1"),
        @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.readOnly", value = "true") }, query = "SELECT sku.stockKeepingUnitNumber "
            + "FROM StockKeepingUnit sku " + "WHERE sku.article = :articleNumber "
            + "AND sku.size = :size " + "AND sku.deleted = 0")
```

Call in Java:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery(StockKeepingUnit.NQ_FINDBY_ARTICLE_AND_SIZE);
query.setParameter(StockKeepingUnit.NQ_PARAM_ARTICLE_NR, articleNumber);
query.setParameter(StockKeepingUnit.NQ_PARAM_SIZE, size);

return (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did you get some exception?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem wit ResultSetMapping :-)

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = StockKeepingUnit.NQ_FIND_ONLY_SKU, columns = {
    @ColumnResult(name = StockKeepingUnit.NQ_RESULT_SKU_NAME)}
```

in NamedQuery you can refer to this mapping with the attribute

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = StockKeepingUnit.NQ_FINDBY_ARTICLE_AND_SIZE, resultSetMapping = StockKeepingUnit.NQ_FIND_ONLY_SKU, query = "SELECT sku.stockKeepingUnitNumber as "
            + StockKeepingUnit.NQ_RESULT_SKU_NAME
            + " FROM StockKeepingUnit sku " + "WHERE sku.article = :articleNumber "
            + "AND sku.size = :size")
```